# Beanshell assertion script failing in Linux machine and working in windows

Tags: jmeter

IN JMeter I want some of the 500 internal server errors to NOT be marked as failures if the response contains a specified text. All 500 server errors are marked as failures.written code to make it as pass for all fail cases.same code is working without error in windows, but getting all samplers are fails in linux machine.

```
    if (ResponseCode.equals("412") == true) 
    { 
         SampleResult.setResponseOK();  
     }
       else if (ResponseCode.equals("500") == true) 
      { 
        SampleResult.setResponseOK();  
        }
```

Comment: what error do you get in jmeter.log ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `SampleResult.setSuccessful(true);`, also remove `== true` which is redundant and remove duplicate code:

```
 if (ResponseCode.equals("412") || ResponseCode.equals("500")) { 
        SampleResult.setResponseOK();  
        SampleResult.setSuccessful(true);
 }
```

Also consider change ResponseCode to responseCode according to Java/Oracle parameter name conventions.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this using [Response Assertion](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Response_Assertion), just check `Ignore Status` box. For example, below configuration mark affected sampler(s) as successful if response will contain `foo`

[image: JMeter Response Assertion]

Check out [Response Assertions in JMeter 3.2 - New and Improved](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/response-assertions-in-jmeter-32-new-and-improved) article for more information on using Response Assertion to add pass/fail criteria logic to your JMeter tests.

---

If you need more complex assertion logic which cannot be achieved using single or multiple Response Assertion instance(s) consider switching to [JSR223 Assertion](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Assertion) as [it is recommended to use Groovy for scripting since JMeter 3.1](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#bsh_scripting)

With regards to your question itself, double check JMeter's "lib" folder of Linux machine contains `bsh-2.0b5.jar` file for Beanshell scripting and `groovy-all-2.4.10.jar` for Groovy scripting.